# Как выбрать шаблонизатор?

Tags: веб-программирование, html, шаблонизаторы, php

Не так давно я столкнулся с тем, что мне понадобился шаблонизатор. Я слышал о smarty, но мне не нравится его идеология. В своих поисках я нашел xtemplate благодаря статье про [классификацию шаблонизаторов](http://www.alabor22.ru/klassifikaciya-shablonizatorov).

Благодаря ей же я увидел, что их много. Естественно у меня появился вопрос. А зачем их столько? Наверняка есть какой-то смысл в том, что их много и они разные.

Поэтому мне бы хотелось узнать, есть ли какие-то преимущества у разных шаблонов для определенных ситуаций. Или же здесь только идеология играет роль.

Comment: А чем smarty не угодил?

Comment: Идеологией.

Comment: Может вы не правильно поняли его идеологию. +1 Smarty

Comment: Шаблонизатор служит для разделения дизайна с кодом.
Я считаю что неприемлемо держать код в шаблонах.
Xtemplate позволяет полностью разделить код и дизайн.
Вопрос в любом случае не о моем мнении.

Comment: Никто Вас не заставляет писать код в шаблонах :) По идее, самый лучший шаблонизатор - это php, просто никто не умеет "держать себя в руках", когда на нем пишут, поэтому требуются как раз всякие "шаблонизаторы". А самый быстрый был и есть - это пых.
Smarty хорош тем, что хорошо умеет кэшировать и я знаю на своем опыте, что большие и нагруженные проекты на нем работают на ура. Решать, конечно, Вам, но лучше либо "держите себя в руках", либо используйте smarty :) Пример того, как можно использовать php как шаблонизатор, в ответах.

Comment: В xtemplate тоже есть кеширование. ) И еще раз призываю смотреть не только историю того, как появился вопрос, но и сам вопрос.

Comment: Кэширование есть у всех :) Без кэширования на сегодняшний день упало бы пол интернета :) А какой собственно вопрос? Как выбрать шаблонизатор? Ответ - молча. А зачем их столько? Чтобы такие люди как Вы сидели и выбирали :) А если серьезно, то шаблонизатор нужно выбирать под свои нужды, если Вам нужен большой проект, то пишите свой, если проект нужно сдать вчера, то пишите на php, если на проект еще есть время и есть желание читать доки, то smarty, xtemplate, zend - нет никакой разницы :) И почему мой ответ не по теме?)

Comment: По тому что отвечает на вопрос как использовать php как шаблонизатор.
А мой вопрос в том по каким критериям выбрать шаблонизатор для определенного проекта. Возможно есть какие то особенности. Естественно кроме идеологии.

Comment: Я ответил Вам на сообщение: "Шаблонизатор служит для разделения дизайна с кодом. Я считаю, что неприемлемо держать код в шаблонах. Xtemplate позволяет полностью разделить код и дизайн.". И написал, что напишу пример в ответах :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, этот линк заменит 1000 слов. :)

[Статья - сравнительный обзор php-шаблонизаторов](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/75901/) и ее [продолжение](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/76021/).

Comment: Не то что я хотел узнать, но спасибо за ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Пример того, как можно использовать php как шаблонизатор:

```
function template($file, $arr = array()) {
    foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) $$k = $v;
    ob_start();
    include $file;
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $data;
}

$data = template("/path/to/template.php", array("param1"=>"value1", "param2"=>"value2"));

print $data;
```

И никто не заставляет писать логику в template.php :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте Ptal http://www.ptal.ru/sintaksis
А также, http://phptal.org/

На ваш вопрос "как выбрать шаблонизатор?", однозначного ответа похоже не существует. Каждый выбирает свое. И тема эта весьма холиварная.

А вот если начать с сути проблемы - "смешанный PHP+HTML код трудночитаем", то получается, что изначальная задача шаблонизатора - улучшить синтаксис. 
Так вот, при выборе шаблонизатора я руководствуюсь именно этим.

Долгое время использовал Smarty. Но затем перешел на Ptal. И теперь использую только его. 
У любого шаблонизатора(у этого тоже) есть большая проблема: порой невозможно написать сложный код. В таких случаях приходится использовать PHP.
Нужно относиться к этому с пониманием и не пытаться сделать на шаблонизаторе всё и вся. Сложные вещи так или иначе придется писать на PHP.

Используйте шаблонизатор в меру, грамотно проектируйте ваше приложение. И все у вас получится.

Выскажусь в пользу TAL шаблонизаторов. Суть шаблонов в том, чтобы задать в них блоки HTML с некоторыми параметрами, с некоторой логикой (например, вывести в цикле данные).
Так вот, TAL архитектура наиболее органично вписывается в HTML код.

Да, порой призодится писать и на чистом PHP. но, по крайней мере, получаются весьма четко разграниченные блоки PHP и HTML. А не полная каша, как если использовать только нативные шаблоны.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте нативные шаблоны. php- сам по себе шаблонизатор

```
<div>
<b><?php echo $var; ?></b>
</div>
```

А смарти и ему подобные - это, по большому счету, компилятор для интерпритатора.

Answer (score 0):

Часто для проектов приходиться ставить шаблонизатор но Smarty хоть и хорош но тяжеловат. Для этого раз написал себе микро-шаблонизатор(не претендуется на самый кульный, уникальность и гениальность) но для небольших проектов хватает с головой.
Сам скрипт класса шаблонизатора

```
<?php
class Tpl_Class
    {
    var $val = array();
    var $Tpl;
    function tpl_get($tpl_name)
        {
        if(empty($tpl_name) OR !file_exists($tpl_name))
            {
            die('Error template');
            }
        else
            {
            $this->html = implode('', file($tpl_name));
            }
        }
    function set_value($key,$var)
        {
        $key = '{'.$key.'}';
        $this->val[$key] = $var;
        }
    function tpl_parsing()
        {
            foreach($this->val as $find => $replace)
                    {
                    $this->html = str_replace($find, $replace, $this->html);
                    }
        }
    }
```

В самом php коде пишешь

```
<?php
DEFINE('DIR_T', 'template/');// определяем путь к папке с шаблонами
include_once DIR."tpl.class.php";// Подключаем класс с шаблонизатором

$tpl=new Tpl_Class;// Создаем новый класс
    $tpl->tpl_get(DIR_T.'index.tpl');//Подключаем шаблон
    $tpl->set_value('TITLE', 'Микро шаблонизатор'); // Title страницы
    $tpl->set_value('TITLE_PAGE', 'Шаблонизатор 21 Века'); // Загаловок страницы
    $tpl->set_value('COPY', '&copy; Peredero Ivan 2011');// Копирайт
    $tpl->tpl_parsing(); // Теперь обрабатываем заменяя переменные в шаблоне на наши данные
    echo $tpl->html;// Выводим обработанный шаблон на экран
```

Ну а в tpl шаблоне понятно что там где TITLE будет `<title>{TITLE}</title>` и  тд